# ElasticSearch: Specify which shard to store data on

Tags: geolocation, sharding, elasticsearch

I wanted to store my data on different shards based on some field value. For example, geo-sharding is something which I am looking for. All my records with continent value 'NA' should go to shard-1, North America; 'EU' should go to shard-2, Europe and so on.

Is there a way I can specify which shard the record (document) should go to?

Tried to find this, but in return I get only the literature associated with shards. Any information on this will be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can influence data repartition with the `routing` parameter. In your case, using the continent name as the routing key will group the documents by a specific continent on the same shard. However, you won't be able to choose **directly**  in which shard store the document.

Here is the [definitive guide section](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/routing-value.html?q=routing) about it, and the [index API documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-routing) concerning `routing`.

Be aware that this can end with some shards/nodes being a lot more used than other.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Is there a way we can specify routing using LogStash? I am trying to find it, but not getting a precise answer

Comment: Take a look at the elasticsearch-output-plugin [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-routing), a `routing` parameter is supported

Comment: Awesome! It works..

Posting my Logstash Config file in case it may of help to someone:
input {stdin{}}
filter {
    csv {
        separator => ","
        columns => ["ID","Continent"]
    }
}
output {
        elasticsearch {
                protocol => "http"
                routing => "%{Continent}"
        }
        stdout {}
}

I checked the /_status; and I see a clear distinction in the documents. Documents with Continent NA go to Shard-3, and those with EU go to Shard-1. Solves the purpose.